# Any other encode like base64?

Tags: java, encoding, apache-axis, encode

Are there some encode algorithm like base64?

I have some `String` that include HTML tag,
I should encode them so that run in my JSON Web service.
the html String like

```
<p>test</p>\r\n\r\n
```

seems not proper for json

I'm try the Java base64 encode my `String`, it's run.
But when I deploy at my machine (axis 2 web service), the encoded String changed...
(it's run well at eclipse, both of them use axis 2)

I'm trying to debug, but have a little of success.

Are there some encode algorithms like base64?

Thanks!

Comment: "I should encode them so that run in my json web service." What do you mean by that? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I agree with LutzHorn. It doesn't make sense to encode HTML data in a JSON string since it's already encoded enough to survive the transport. Encoding it in base64 is futile.

Comment: the data one for web, generate by html editor,it's full of html tag.but the data alse provide to mobile app, but it's not support html tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is JavaScript, so you probably want to escape them appropriately for JavaScript.  JavaScript escapes characters with \nn where 'nn' is the hexadecimal value of the character.

In your example, the encoding would be

```
\60p\62test\60\47p\62\13\10\13\10
```

Answer (score 0):

XXE, UUE, binhex, Base32, Base85, Ascii85

https://cryptii.com/pipes/ascii85-encoding